# How can i make so that when a layer is added to a map it is added as the bottom layer in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to figure out a good way to switch maptypes and add the layer as the bottom layer. The other layers are information layers that should be on top always. I tried to use the map.baseLayer property but the layer is still rendered on top of the other layers.

Here is what i got:

```
var OSMLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

// Initial map
var currentMap = OSMLayer;

var mapQuestOSMLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
});

var mapQuestSATLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});
var mapQuestHYBLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'hyb'})
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [OSMLayer],
  target: document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});

// How can i set the layer as the bottom layer?

$('#btnMapTypes ul.dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e) {
    map.removeLayer(currentMap);
    switch($(this).attr('data-type')){
        case 'OSM':
            map.addLayer(OSMLayer);
            map.baseLayer = OSMLayer;
            currentMap = OSMLayer;
        break;
        case 'mapQuestOSM':
            map.addLayer(mapQuestOSMLayer);
            map.baseLayer = mapQuestOSMLayer;
            currentMap = mapQuestOSMLayer;
        break;
        case 'mapQuestSAT':
            map.addLayer(mapQuestSATLayer);
            map.baseLayer = mapQuestSATLayer;
            currentMap = mapQuestSATLayer;
        break;
        case 'mapQuestHYB':
            map.addLayer(mapQuestHYBLayer);
            map.baseLayer = mapQuestHYBLayer;
            currentMap = mapQuestHYBLayer;
        break;
    }           
});
```

What is the proper way of achieving the result im looking for? Thanks!

Comment: What is the point if you click to add a layer but (that added) the layer keeps hidden, at the bottom of others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do getLayers on the map, you get a collection, which has the functions to manipulate order, for instance insertAt (or setAt depending on your needs): http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Collection.html

Comment: Super! Just what i needed. Thanks!